# How to reshape multichannel image with a PyTorch encoder?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I have a tensor with dimensions `[18, 512, 512]`, representing grayscale heatmaps for up to 18 specific objects on a 512x512 image. In order to generate a suitable representation of this image for my conditional GAN, I need to reshape this tensor into a `[512, 4, 4]` shape using an encoder. However, I can't understand how this transformation can be achieved, since given dimensions apppear too mismatched for direct linear or convolutional transformations.

```
class HeatmapEncoder(torch.nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    # source = 18x512x512
    # target = 512x4x4
    self.encoder = torch.nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear()
    )

    def forward(self, x):
      pass
```

It is possible to use `nn.Flatten()' with start_dim=0 here, but the result will be a simplified tensor that can't be used as an input by the linear layer.
The decoder part is not especially important right now, since I only need a low-dimensional representation of the heatmaps to condition my GAN and not to recreate those images.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a couple of different approaches for your problem, like viewing it as a one big vector then slowly reducing it to your size, or permuting dimensions and applying different operations etc. Since there is no full code for testing it on the actual problem, I can't really say which will work better, but my first instinct says convolution based dimension reductions is quite suitable for this problem. First code, then talk:

```
class ReduceConv(torch.nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, nin, nout, activ=nn.ReLU):
    super(ReduceConv, self).__init__()

    # source = Batch x nin x H x W
    # target = Batch x nout x (H/2) x (W/2)

    self.conv = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(
            nin, nout,
            kernel_size=3,
            stride=1,
            padding=1),
        nn.Conv2d(
            nout, nout,
            kernel_size=3,
            stride = 2,
            padding = 1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(nout),
        activ()
    )

  def forward(self, x):
    return self.conv(x)

class HeatmapEncoder(torch.nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(HeatmapEncoder, self).__init__()

    # source = 18x512x512
    # target = 512x4x4
    self.encoder = torch.nn.Sequential(
        ReduceConv(18, 32),       # out->  32 256 256 
        ReduceConv(32, 64),       # out->  64 128 128
        ReduceConv(64, 64),       # out->  64 64 64
        ReduceConv(64, 64),       # out->  64 32 32
        ReduceConv(64, 128),      # out-> 128 16 16
        ReduceConv(128, 256),     # out-> 256 8 8
        ReduceConv(256, 512)      # out-> 512 4 4
    )

  def forward(self, x):
    return self.encoder(x)

# 10 is batch size
inp = torch.rand(10, 18, 512, 512)
enc = HeatmapEncoder()
out = enc(inp)
print(inp.shape)      # torch.Size([10, 18, 512, 512])
print(out.shape)      # torch.Size([10, 512, 4, 4])
```

It is essentially just a stack of convolution layers. Note that, in each ReduceConv layer input dimensions are halved by using stride=2 convolutions. You don't technically need the first convolution in the ReduceConv layer, but it is deep learning era, more the merrier :) I've also added BatchNorm after each reduction along with an activation function. 18 is regarded as channels when inputted to first convolution. This way channels build up to 512 while the width and height is halved after each operation. This encoder model probably not the best or most efficient one but it should be good enough for your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the code, it does work as expected. However, one of my background helper functions raises an error with this in the stack trace:

`assert (nan_to_num(tensor) == nan_to_num(other)).all(), fullname
AssertionError: Generator.synthesis.heatmap_encoder.encoder.0.conv.2.running_mean`.
I can't figure out what causes this error, since those convolutional layers should not introduce any weird NaN handling by themselves.

Comment: What is the helper function for? From the assertion, it looks like just checking tensor==other for all values after replacing NaN values which has failed on Generator.synthesis.heatmap_encoder.encoder.0.conv.2.running_mean. Running_mean is part of batch normalization, it tracks the running mean of batches. If you have forwarded input to network in training mode, running_mode will be updated. If your helper function requires it to be same after forwarding, try running network in eval() mode.

Comment: The function is supposed to check `DistributedDataParallel` consistency across processes, and errors do not appear if I train my network without using DDP. But this isn't viable with the scope of this project. As you suggest, I will try switching `HeatmapEncoder` itself to eval() mode manually, although I believed it to be the default.